# How to install console application using ActiveX

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to install console application on client machine.

It is possible to launch this console application as **ActiveX** or any other possible solution ?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

I have a silverlight player which playing with web browser IE. I'm controlling stop, play , pause  with USB hardware footpedal. so I have implemented console application to detect footpedal command.therefor I want to give option to client machine for installing this console application using activeX control in IE.

Comment: Please add more detail why do you want to create it as an activex is that because you want to use IE to install it for instance ?
Sorry I could not get the question correctly

Comment: What is the console application supposed to do on client machine? Access some local resources or just display some data?

Comment: BTW how user gonna use it should IE execute it or you just wanted to install it and user will run it when they needed

Comment: Thanks for reply
I have a silverlight player which playing with web browser. 
I'm controlling playing control silverlight player with USB hardware footpedal. so I have implemented console application to detect footpedal command and control player (stop , pause).

Comment: Why can't you just have the ActiveX control itself do the detecting, or the silver-light player.